# Spring, Prime Faces application not showing CSS when deploying to Heroku

Tags: java, css, spring, heroku, primefaces

I am working with Spring 3.1.3, Prime Faces 3.4.2, Hibernate 3.6.8 and Pretty Faces 2.0.4.

The CSS is showing when I deploy the app in a local Server (Apache Tomcat 7), but when I deploy the same project to Heroku the CSS is not showing.

This is how I input the CSS in my main.xhtml template file:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="custom.css" />
```

This is the result in the html source (local server):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/evaluation-cloud/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-cupertino" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/evaluation-cloud/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap.css.jsf?ln=css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/evaluation-cloud/javax.faces.resource/custom.css.jsf?ln=css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/evaluation-cloud/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces" />
```

This is the result in the html source when deployed to Heroku

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-cupertino" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="//javax.faces.resource/bootstrap.css.jsf?ln=css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="//javax.faces.resource/custom.css.jsf?ln=css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="//javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces" />
```

Notice the '//' in the href

I don't know why this is happening. If someone have experienced the same issue please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the configuration to use jetty runner and that solved the problem.